# Sort an amount of user entered numbers according to size (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, math, user-input

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a user defined number of user defined numbers according to size, the user defined numbers are doubles.

I'm trying to do it without using arrays or anything too complex, ideally using some form or combination of `Math.min` and `Math.max`

eg

```
int lowestNumber = (int)Math.min(firstNumber, (Math.min(secondNumber, Math.min(thirdNumber, finalNumber) )));
```

This gets me the lowest number, that's fine, but when i try and do

```
int secondLowestNumber = (int)Math.min(lowestNumber, firstNumber,(Math.min(secondNumber, Math.min(thirdNumber, finalNumber))));
```

I get the lowest number again. I guess the problem is that I don't know how to eliminate the lowest number once I've completed the first assignment.

Comment: `I'm trying to do it without using arrays` - Why? Using Arrays is the easiest solution. Just use Arrays.sort(...);

Comment: @camickr ...or `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: @MattBall, agreed an ArrayList would be better since you don't need to know the size of the list in advance.

Comment: I'm lost as to what "sort user entered number according to size" means. What size?

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear enough, by size i mean how big or small the number is.

Comment: also, the reason for not using arrays is basically because i'm a university student and haven't been taught arrays yet, i've done some research myself and think i can figure out how to do an array, but i'm assuming that since i haven't been taught arrays yet, there must be a way to do it that doesn't involve arrays. i know that i can do it using arrays easily, but i worry that if i use arrays before i'm taught them to solve a problem that can be done without arrays, i might miss out on some knowledge that might prove helpful later.

Comment: @Alex It seems like you haven't told us the complete question yet since your examples imply that the number of numbers is bounded (i.e. the user only enters exactly four numbers). If the input is bounded to four numbers then you can hardcode a sorting algorithm which seems to be what you were doing. The issue with your second line is that `Math.min(lowestNumber, ANY_OF_THE_OTHER_NUMBERS)` will return `lowestNumber` because... it's the smallest number as evidenced by your first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize the comments on your original question:

You can sort using an ArrayList very easily using Collections.sort().  Here's an example:

```
    //lets say we have these three numbers:
    int num1 = 2, num2 = 5, num3 = 3;

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(num1);
    list.add(num2);
    list.add(num3);

    System.out.println(list);

    Collections.sort(list);

    System.out.println(list);
```

The above results in the output:

```
[2, 5, 3]
[2, 3, 5]
```

As expected!

Note we can generalize this using for loops to add more numbers or use other primitive numbers than ints...  Let me know if you need other details!

Comment: Thanks for the help Jlewis, Arrays are clearly the best way to do it and i appreciate your advice!